# Azure Function to LogicApps Integration

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am creating an Azure Function which is based on Timer Trigger. The fucntion will collect data from cosmos db and send an email using SendGrid output binding.

Now i need to trigger logicapps to update the cosmos db as processed.

Problem:
I am planning to use Http output to send the request to logicApps. But i read that http output can be configured if the in trigger is http. So how can i trigger to logic apps from function

Comment: What is your requirement with timer trigger and what cron expression are you using?

Comment: the fucntion will trigger in every 2 minute and check the cosmosdb data and send email. After that i need to update the data as email sent

Answer (score 0):

> the fucntion will trigger in every 2 minute and check the cosmosdb data and send email. After that i need to update the data as email sent.

As per your requirement, you can directly use `When a new email arrives (V3)` trigger having confined folder selected for it, so that the message will be read and then will be processed for the next steps. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

*Results:*

[image]

[image]

### Update

For demonstration purposes, I have considered `json1` to be the data that is sent to user through mail.

```
namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 0/2 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // You can replace the URI with your Logic App Post request URI
                string uri = "<LOGICAPP_POST_REQUEST_URI>";

                // Place the below before output binding
                string json1 = "{\"a\": \"someValue\",\"b\": [{\"c\": \"someValue\",\"d\": [{\"e\": 5,\"f\": 6},{\"e\": 7,\"f\": 8}]}],\"g\": \"someValue\"}";
                var jsonDeserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json1);
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonDeserialised);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can replace the url in the above code with the Post URL of your Logic App.

[image]

*Results:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you but email send to users. So that will not be a trigger . I want to send an email and also send a request to logicapps to update

Comment: sure, I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you and please. I am passing list of ids to the service bus queue to update all in the logicapps

Comment: Thank you for your time. Actually I am not lookking this manual way  because i am thinking if this takes time not good for function app. I used Service Bus quoue output binding so i have timer trigger and 2 output binding SendGrid and ServiceBus . is this fine?

Comment: AFAIK thats the only way that you can integrate your function app with logic apps considering the Azure timer trigger. Also, it just that you need to include the url of logic app and nothing else is manual. I just took a sample data just to show how this way works, but you can replace it with your data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252968/discussion-between-swethakandikonda-and-akhil).